# Mongodb nested inserts

Tags: mongodb, nested

My data below, now favoriteapi will have key/value records coming in and going out.

how can i insert data into this nested element

```
{

"firstname": "ram5656",
"lastname": "rahul",
"email": "ram@ram.com",
"password": "encrypt",
"favoriteapi" : [ 
    {
        "api_id" : "function",
        "api_name" : "enterprise"
    }, 
    {
        "api_id" : "data_subject_category",
        "api_name" : "address"
    }, 
    {
        "api_id" : "data_subject",
        "api_name" : "address"
    }
],
"is_active": true,
"create_ts": "2016-05-18T00:00:00.000Z",
"create_by": "ram@ram.com",
"update_ts": "2016-05-18T06:00:00.000Z",
"update_by": "ram@ram.com",
"lastlogin": "2016-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

}

i tried this

```
var updatedocument =     
    {
        "api_id" : "sanket",
        "api_name" : "sanket"
    }

user.favoriteapi.insert(updatedocument, options);
```

but, no luck.

should i use upsert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do an [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) on your user document, and specify that you want to [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) a new sub-document to the *favouriteapi* array.

```js
var updatedocument = {
    "api_id" : "sanket",
    "api_name" : "sanket"
};

db.user.update(
  {"email": "ram@ram.com"},
  {$push: {
      "favouriteapi" : updatedocument
    }
  }
);
```